# INSERT When multiple values not present

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I'm using SQL Server 2012, and the code I'm using *does* work, but I **know** it isn't the correct way to do it.

I'm trying to add rows to a table only when the values are not already present, but from two different columns.

```
INSERT INTO #TEMP_Final
SELECT
a.ClaimNbr
,a.DisputeNbr
,a.DisputeAmt
,a.CardAcctNbr
,b.CreditAmt
,b.CreditRefNbr
FROM #TEMP_Disputes a
    JOIN #TEMP_Credits b
    ON a.CardAcctNbr = b.CardAcctNbr
    AND a.DisputeAmt = b.CreditAmt * -1
    AND a.DisputeRowNbr = b.CreditRowNbr
WHERE a.DisputeNbr NOT IN (SELECT DisputeNbr FROM #TEMP_Final)
AND b.CreditRefNbr NOT IN (SELECT CreditRefNbr FROM #TEMP_Final)
```

Is there a more appropriate way to achieve the same results?

Thanks.

Comment: There are a bunch of different ways you could do this, but I don't see what's wrong with your method (the only issue would be if you could have null values for disputenbr or creditrefnbr). Other possible solutions might be to left join to your #TEMP_FINAL table on a.disputenbr or b.creditrefnbr and only insert where the left join is null, or just replacing your in clause with an exists clause.

Comment: Look at MERGE() for an alternative method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use NOT EXIST clause... You can avoid NOT IN queries.

```
INSERT INTO #TEMP_Final
SELECT
 a.ClaimNbr
 ,a.DisputeNbr
 ,a.DisputeAmt
 ,a.CardAcctNbr
 ,b.CreditAmt
 ,b.CreditRefNbr
FROM #TEMP_Disputes a
    JOIN #TEMP_Credits b
        ON a.CardAcctNbr = b.CardAcctNbr
         AND a.DisputeAmt = b.CreditAmt * -1
         AND a.DisputeRowNbr = b.CreditRowNbr
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM #TEMP_Final f 
                 WHERE f.DisputeNbr=a.DisputeNbr
                       AND f.CreditRefNbr=b.CreditRefNbr)
```